# How to extract a specific value from a Request Body in POSTMAN and save in a variable

Tags: postman

Is there any way to get a specific value (`businessType`) from the Request body and save in a variable in postman?

Request Body

```
{
    "fein": "nurrk",
    "businessType": "LLP",
    "incorporationYear": 1993,
    "incorporationState": "stateelesss",
    "annualRevenue": 1000,
    "companyActivity": "Producctiionn",
    "stockSymbol": "starer",
    "mcc": "qa12345"
}
```

[image: POSTMAN SS]

I've been using different commands and none of them seems to work

```
var reqBody = JSON.parse(request.data);
```

Comment: Yes, I need to extract a certain value from request body

Comment: What value? This question lacks any detail and context. Format the response code and add the text, if that's in the console then it's part of the response body in the app. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is my request body, i need to extract businessType from it and save in a variable in POSTMAN tests tab.

Comment: Please view the screenshot

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Comment: I've been using different commands and none of them seems to work, like var reqBody = JSON.parse(request.data);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `pm.request` to get data from the request body:

```
let businessType = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw).businessType;

pm.environment.set('businessType', businessType);
```

More information about the `pm.*` API can be found here:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/